# extracting element text value

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am using `JAXB` to generate code for unmarshalling xml into java entities using an `xsd` file for schematics.  The problem is that the resulting code does not generate the `name` of an `organization` specified in the following xml:

```
<organization>
    <name>Some organization's name goes here</name>
</organization>
```

Here is the xsd definition for the `Organization` data type:

```
<xs:complexType name="Organization">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="ON" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="classCode" type="EntityClassOrganization" use="optional" fixed="ORG"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Here is the `xsd` definition for the `ON` datatype:

```
<xs:complexType name="ON" mixed="true">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        A name for an organization. A sequence of name parts.
     </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="delimiter" type="en.delimiter"/>
        <xs:element name="prefix" type="en.prefix"/>
        <xs:element name="suffix" type="en.suffix"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="use" use="optional" type="set_EntityNameUse">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            A set of codes advising a system or user which name
            in a set of like names to select for a given purpose.
            A name without specific use code might be a default
            name useful for any purpose, but a name with a specific
            use code would be preferred for that respective purpose.
        </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

Here is the resulting java code created by `JAXB`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ON", propOrder = {"content"})
public class ON {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "delimiter", namespace = "urn:something", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "prefix", namespace = "urn:something", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "suffix", namespace = "urn:something", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "use")
    protected List<String> use;

    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();}
        return this.content;
    }

    public List<String> getUse() {
        if (use == null) {use = new ArrayList<String>();}
        return this.use;
    }
}
```

There are several problems with this resulting java class.  First off, it creates `List<Serializable> content;` instead of creating separate properties for `delimiter`, `prefix`, and `suffix`.  And just as importantly, it also fails to give me access to the text value inside the `name` tags in the xml at top.  When I remove the `mixed="true"` from the `ON` definition in the xsd file, the content list is replaced with separate properties for the `delimiter`, `prefix`, and `suffix`, but I still can't get the text content of the `name` element.  I hesitate to remove `mixed=true` because I read that mixed=true specified that a `complextype` can contain `elements`, `attributes`, and `text`.

How can I change the code above so that is generates a method for retrieving the text of the `name` element in addition to generating separate methods for each of the other elements/properties?

Answer (score 0):

Try my [Simplify plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Simplify+Plugin). I am not exactly sure that it does what you want, but it is written for the similar case.

Example:

```
<xs:complexType name="typeWithElementsProperty">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="b" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Gives you:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "a", type = String.class)
    @XmlElement(name = "b", type = Integer.class),
})
protected List<Serializable> aOrB;
```

But with the simplify plugin:

```
<xs:complexType name="typeWithElementsProperty">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <simplify:as-element-property/>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="b" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

You'll get:

```
@XmlElement(name = "a", type = String.class)
protected List<String> a;
@XmlElement(name = "b", type = Integer.class)
protected List<Integer> b;
```

You have a somewhat similar case, you get your property because of the `mixed="true"`.

If this does not work for the mixed types OOTB, please send me a PR with your test case [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/blob/master/tests/issues/src/main/resources/schema.xsd) and file an issue [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/issues).

**UPDATE**

I have implemented [this feature](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/issues/1).

From [this](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/blob/master/tests/issues/src/main/resources/schema.xsd#L335-L346):

```
<xs:complexType name="gh1" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string">
            <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <simplify:as-element-property/>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="b" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType>
```

You'll get this:

```
protected List<String> a;
@XmlElement(type = Integer.class)
protected List<Integer> b;
@XmlMixed
protected List<String> content;
```

Will be in the next version (0.9.0).

Comment: you did not answer my question.  I am trying to get the text content of the name element without losing the attributes or subnodes. I do not mean to be critical, but it seems like you just posted an advertisement for your web site without really considering my question.

Comment: Well, I though this "There are several problems with this resulting java class. First off, it creates List<Serializable> content; instead of creating separate properties for delimiter, prefix, and suffix." was a part of your question, was it not? The plugin I've "advertised" aims at exactly this point. You ARE asking how to separate properties in the last line, the plugin in question does exactly that. Do you still think my answer is not appropriate?

Textual content of your element should be in the `List<Serializable>` property you get, after all, `String` is `Serializable`.

Comment: I know I can get rid of the `XmlElementRefs` by getting rid of the `mixed` attribute in the xsd.  But doing so leaves me without access to the textual component of the `name` element.  My question is how to access the textual component of the `name` element after I get rid of the `XmlElementRefs` via deleting `mixed`. I don't see how the architects at oracle could have neglected this to the point where it requires a third party library to be added.

Comment: There is no `getContent()` method for the `ON` class produced by the code above, even when I delete the `mixed` attribute of the `xsd` that defines the class parameters for `JAXB`.

Comment: `getContent()` should be a string for the textual contents of the element.

Comment: if I remove the elements from the `ON` declaration in the `xsd` file, but keep the `mixed="true"`, the `getContent()` method returns a string with the textual content of the node.  But doing so causes a loss of the `delimiter`, `prefix`, `suffix`, etc.

Comment: I think that on the Java class level you can achieve this by several element properties for `delimiter`, `prefix` and `suffix` and additionally `@XmlMixed @XmlAnyElement`. But I don't think you can generate it without a third party tool.

So, sorry, you seem like puting yourself in a position where you can't be helped.

Comment: See the update. The Simplify plugin can now handle your case (in the snapshot version, not yet released).

Comment: I will get back to you when I have had time to change my level of abstraction about this.  Hopefully tomorrow.  Thank you.