# How to use XStream for List<Object>?

Tags: java, jaxb, xstream

I want to make mappings according to JAXB and XStream.

Here is snippet of code:

```
@XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "Success", type = SuccessType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "Warnings", type = WarningsType.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "BagTypes", type = HashMap.class)
})
protected List<Object> successAndWarningsAndBagTypes;
```

How to make similar annotation mappings for `List<Object>` with XStream?

Or simpler and better will be to divide this `List<Object>` to separate class instances?

***update***:

I have to map this snippet of code according this xml file:

```
<EI_BaggageTypesRS Version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <Success/>
    <BagTypes>
        <ResponseBagType>
            <code>AA</code>
            <description>Golf Bag</description>
        </ResponseBagType>
        <ResponseBagType>
            <code>BA</code>
            <description>Skis</description>
        </ResponseBagType>
        <ResponseBagType>
            <code>DA</code>
            <description>Snow Board</description>
        </ResponseBagType>
        <ResponseBagType>
            <code>CA</code>
            <description>Fishing Gear</description>
        </ResponseBagType>
        <ResponseBagType>
            <code>EA</code>
            <description>Surf Board</description>
        </ResponseBagType>
    </BagTypes>
</EI_BaggageTypesRS>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: need more code snippet.

Comment: @yogeshprajapati I updated question with xml file.

Comment: Do you generate your classes from some XML schema using XJC? Or write them manually?

Comment: @lexicore This code was generated by `wsimport`. It internally uses JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code is generated from an XML schema, I will answer this question:

> Or simpler and better will be to divide this List to separate
>   class instances?

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107727/extracting-element-text-value/26108534#26108534). One way to split your `successAndWarningsAndBagTypes` would be using my [Simplify plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Simplify+Plugin). You can use `simplify:as-element-property` to split one `@XmlElements` property into several `@XmlElement` (without `s` at the end) properties. For example, from this:

```
<xs:complexType name="typeWithElementsProperty">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <simplify:as-element-property/>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="b" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

You'll get this:

```
@XmlElement(name = "a", type = String.class)
protected List<String> a;
@XmlElement(name = "b", type = Integer.class)
protected List<Integer> b;
```

However I'm not sure how to use JAXB plugins with `wsimport`. Must be possible, just never tried this.